# Identifying Capacitors

Tags: capacitor, identification

I bought a mixed bag of ceramic capacitors from Maplin and I'm struggling to identify most of them. I'm a bit of an electronics newb, but I understood that a capacitor usually has 3 numbers on and sometimes a letter at the end of the numbers.  The third number indicates the amount of zeros you add to the first two to get the value in pF.  Am I correct?

Well with that in mind, I introduce you to:

[image]

[image]

The first one is a bit blurry, but it seems to have 8P2 printed on it.  Next has n51 with Sy below it.  The 3rd and 5th ones have a horizontal line under the number, and what might be a number one, or a corresponding vertical line, can't decide which it is.  The 4th one seems a bit more clear now that I can see the writing more clearly in the picture - I assume this is 180pF?  Finally the last one has 82 on it, is this simply 82pF?

Is there a way to test the capacitance at all?  I have countless smaller ones with either blurry text, or nothing written on.

Comment: Do you have a DMM with a capacitance setting, or an oscilloscope to do the measurement manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

8p2 = 8.2 pF

n51 = 0.51 nF

220 pF

180 pF

560 pF

82 pF

Comment: The rightmost cap in the top row looks more like "221" to me, so I'd vote for 220pF - I concur with the rest of your statements.

Comment: I think you are right. I've changed it.

Comment: An LC meter that outputs in Morse code...right.  I figured with the FCC no longer requiring hams to know Morse meant it could be pronounced dead once and for all :P

Answer (score 6):

The three numbers form, let's say XYZ(J), means XY x {10^Z} pF, e.g. 560 = 56 pF, 561 = 560 pF, 562 = 5.6 nF etc.

Cheap digital multimeters don't usually measure capacitances in this range, but you can build capacitance meter easily, there's plenty of schematics on the internet, just google "capacitance meter schematics".

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](http://www.elecraft.com/Apps/caps.htm) page interesting, when I had similar problems.